TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous, Defining new feature for Rossman Dataset, Kaggle
So I'm creating a new feature for the Rossman Dataset (available on Kaggle), and I want to make the Promo Feature in this DataSet into some Features like this feature that tells how many month have passed since a Promo was launched in this store.
So here's the DataFrame:enter image description here
And the features I draw with red and blue is the ones I'm talking about.
The code I scripted is:
def check_promo_month(row):
    month2str = {1:'Jan', 2:'Feb', 3:'Mar', 4:'Apr', 5:'May', 6:'Jun',              
                 7:'Jul', 8:'Aug', 9:'Sept', 10:'Oct', 11:'Nov', 12:'Dec'}
    try:
        months = (row['PromoInterval'] or '').split(',')
        if row['Promo2Open'] and month2str[row['Month']] in months:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    except Exception:
        return 0

def promo_cols(df):
    # Months since Promo2 was open
    df['Promo2Open'] = 12 * (df.Year - df.Promo2SinceYear) +  (df.WeekOfYear - df.Promo2SinceWeek)*7/30.5
    df['Promo2Open'] = df['Promo2Open'].map(lambda x: 0 if x < 0 else x).fillna(0) * df['Promo2']
    # Whether a new round of promotions was started in the current month
    df['IsPromo2Month'] = df.apply(check_promo_month, axis=1) * df['Promo2']

then i want to use them:
promo_cols(merged_df)
promo_cols(merged_test_df)

But I kept recieving this massage, I tried pd.na , np.na,....
but nothing works.
I was expecting something like this:
merged_df[['Date', 'Promo2', 'Promo2SinceYear', 'Promo2SinceWeek', 'PromoInterval', 'Promo2Open', 'IsPromo2Month']].sample(20):

enter image description here

Please read up on minimal reproducible examples. It is very difficult to read images of dataframes. Please include them in the post as formatted text.
